# How to store go channel value into some other data type(string,byte[]) and reassign it other go channel

Tags: go

//Target --> convert str(or some byte[])into channel variable newpipe.
I have to transfer my data from one process to another my making xml.
Xml marshall does not support chan type does not work with interface{} also
then after receveing response xml from other process assign value to newpipe and use newpipe for channel communication

```
func main() {
    mypipe := make(chan int)
    fmt.Printf("My pipe addr %p \n", mypipe)
    str := fmt.Sprintf("%p", mypipe) //way to convert mypipe to byte[]
    var newpipe chan int
}
```

I am looking for various type conversion for one day but none of them works with chan type

Comment: I think you're overthinking this, what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: that won't work, you will either 1. use 1 "go" process to handle rabbitmq/subprocess or use multiple go processes and use sockets.

Comment: @OneOfOne I understand u are suggesting that every instance should communicate on sockets to communicate with other subsystem. But please explain why my approach will not work.

Comment: a channel is allocated in that specific process' memory space, it's not something you can share between processes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51918/discussion-between-user2383973-and-oneofone)

Answer (score 2):

The code below will convert an incoming string into an outgoing byte-slice. Hopefully that's what you're after:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func stringToByteSlice(sc chan string, bc chan []byte) {
    defer close(bc)
    for s := range sc {
        bc <- []byte(s)
    }
}

func main() {
    strings := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz", "bat"}
    byteSlices := [][]byte{}
    sc := make(chan string)
    bc := make(chan []byte)
    go func() {
        defer close(sc)
        for _, s := range strings {
            sc <- s
        }
    }()
    go stringToByteSlice(sc, bc)
    for b := range bc {
        byteSlices = append(byteSlices, b)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", byteSlices)
}
```

Outputs:

> [[102 111 111] [98 97 114] [98 97 122] [98 97 116]]

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/IuUP2FdHvQ)

Comment: My target is to make a channel of any type(string,[]byte) now as a channel return a memory address. Store that address to string or []byte.Make another channel of same type(string,[]byte) and now assign the memory address to this channel.

Comment: @user2383973 that can be done (I think) with the `unsafe` and `reflect` packages, but it basically eliminates the type safety of Go. Have a look at http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#MakeChan . My guess is that you're approaching this from the wrong angle. Have a look at http://blog.golang.org/share-memory-by-communicating .